# Pass parameters into xbbg's bhd function dynamically

Tags: python, parameters, eval, getattr

I need to make a bloomberg request using xbbgs' bdh function. I want to pass on additional parameters, which is not working properly.

My request:

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdh("LBUSTRUU Index","OPTION_ADJ_DURATION_SOV_CRV","2020-07-08 07:28:56.125413","2020-07-15 08:49:55.742602",CHARACTERISTICS_SOURCE_OVERRIDE = "RETURN")
```

My question now is: how can I pass the optional parameter CHARACTERISTICS_SOURCE_OVERRIDE as a dynamic string/variable?

My (wrong) guess was to use sth.:

```
dt_end=(pd.datetime.today() - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(1))
dt_start=(end_date - pd.tseries.offsets.BDay(5))
ticker="LBUSTRUU Index"
field= "OPTION_ADJ_DURATION_SOV_CRV"
param="\"" + CHARACTERISTICS_SOURCE_OVERRIDE = "RETURN" + "\""

blp.bdh(ticker, field, start_date=dt_start, end_date=dt_end,eval(param))
```